# Only first characteristic being updated

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, core-bluetooth

I am working on a core bluetooth project where a service needs to update two characteristics when a button is pressed. However, only the first update method returns YES. The second returns no and does  not change the value. Does anyone know how I could get both of these characteristics to update?

```
-(void)sendData:(NSData *)question Name:(NSData*)name{
    //send Data

    NSLog(@"Name:%@ Question:%@",name, question);

    //returns yes
    NSLog(@"%d", [self.peripheralManager updateValue:name forCharacteristic:self.nameCharacteristic onSubscribedCentrals:nil]);

    //returns no

    NSLog(@"%d", [self.peripheralManager updateValue:question forCharacteristic:self.questionCharacteristic onSubscribedCentrals:nil]);

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix CBPeripheralManager's transmit queue is full?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240447/how-to-fix-cbperipheralmanagers-transmit-queue-is-full)